# CSS Menu display issues in Mobile Web Browser

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, drop-down-menu, cross-browser

My site is:
http://chanbaneng.com/demo/

When I browse using mobile browser like Samsung smartphones' default browser, I can not view the drop down menu under "Partners". It works fine if I'm using Chrome mobile.

The biggest problem is, for some mobile browsers like the default one in Samsung Galaxy S5 and Note 3, include iPad and iPhone, the whole menu is gone, and left with a drop down on the right corner. When click, the whole menu content is out of place.

Anything I can do to fix this?

I'm thinking of detecting mobile browser and display a message and ask them use Chrome, however I don't know how to "not display" the message when the mobile browser is already Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

please Try the below code.

```
/*style.cs line no.246*/

#cssmenu ul.open li, #cssmenu > ul.open > li { 
    clear: both; /*new edit*/
    display: block; 
}
```

Comment: Amazing how 1 line of code fixed the problem, it now displays as a drop-down, it'll do. Just 1 minor problem, the last menu (contact) is out of the black drop down box, anyway I can squeeze it in?

Comment: Try it in style.cs - line no.194  #cssmenu > ul { display: inline-block; height: auto; }

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work, it makes the menu open up all as default, but it's blocking the slider image and it's messed up.

Comment: Try this again #cssmenu > ul {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 28%;
    width: auto !important;
}

Comment: Really thanks for the help, just 1 final touch up and it's good. The contact us now fit into the box, but the default black bar became too thick and covered the content below it, I think something to do with the height and we're done? http://i.imgur.com/ZBZwrwm.jpg